# Booked a shooting (pictures) in Miami - my trip was canceled

Tags: contract-law

On the 6th of september I booked a photoshoot in Miami (I am from germany), my trip was later canceled and I can't go to Miami Beach. I think you all know about Hurricane Irma...
My Photoshoot costs overall 2k and I already paid 500 upfront. The contract says that if I cancel the shoot the 500 dollars will be kept by the photographer. Which  I can understand, since he might lose other clients the same day.

However, do you think this is okay? I lost my complete flights to the U.S. and suffered already some k in money. 
The 500 dollars i paid were agreed by both sides, but it could be 300 or 600, we simply thought there will be no reason to not make the shooting.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Often contracts have a force majeure clause to cover situations like this.

Comment: This is what travel insurance is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally this is perfectly ok: claim it on your travel insurance.